# How can I iterate through a doc2vec model?

Tags: python, nlp, doc2vec

I have built a Doc2Vec model and am trying to get the vectors of all my testing set (176 points). The code below I can only see one vector at a time. I want to be able to do "clean_corpus[404:]" to get the entire data set but when I try that it still outputs one vector.

```
model.save("d2v.model")
print("Model Saved")


from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec

model= Doc2Vec.load("d2v.model")
#to find the vector of a document which is not in training data
test_data = clean_corpus[404]
v1 = model.infer_vector(test_data)
print("V1_infer", v1)
```

Is there a way to easily iterate over the model to get and save all 176 vectors?

Answer (score 1):

Because `.infer_vector()` takes a single text (list-of-words), you would want to call it multiple times in a loop if you need to infer many separate vectors for many different documents.

Another option would be to include *all* the documents of interest in the `Doc2Vec` model training data, including your test set. Then, you can simply request the learned-during-training vectors for any document, by the unique `tag` you supplied during training.

Whether this is an acceptable practice depends on other unstated aspects of your project goals. `Doc2Vec` is an unsupervised algorithm, so in some cases it can be appropriate to use *all* available text to improve its training. (It doesn't necessarily cause the same problems as contaminating the training of a supervised classifier with the same already-labeled examples you'll be testing it against.)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (not the cheapest though) is to iterate through the test set and then run it through the `.infer_vector()` function.

```
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument

documents = [TaggedDocument(doc, [i]) for i, doc in enumerate(common_texts)]
model = Doc2Vec(documents, vector_size=5, window=2, min_count=1, workers=4)

sentence = "This is a system response".split()  # sentence is of list(str) type.
vector = model.infer_vector(sentence)

print(vector)
```

And for multiple sentences:

```
import numpy as np


sentences = [
    "This is a system response".split(), 
    "That is a hello world thing".split()
]

vectors = np.array([model.infer_vector(s) for s in sentences])
```

---

But looking at the code https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/62669aef21ae8047c3105d89f0032df81e73b4fa/gensim/models/doc2vec.py

There's a `.dv` which means doc vectors that you can use to retrieve the vectors used to train the model. E.g.

```
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument

documents = [TaggedDocument(doc, [i]) for i, doc in enumerate(common_texts)]
model = Doc2Vec(documents, vector_size=5, window=2, min_count=1, workers=4)

print('No. of docs:', len(documents))
print('No. of doc vectors:',len(model.docvecs))
```

[out]:

```
No. of docs: 9
No. of doc vectors: 9
```

And if we add more 2 sentences:

```
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument

documents = [TaggedDocument(doc, [i]) for i, doc in enumerate(common_texts)]

model = Doc2Vec(documents, vector_size=5, window=2, min_count=1, workers=4)

original_len = len(documents)
print('No. of original docs:', original_len)
print('No. of original doc vectors:',len(model.docvecs))
print('-----')

# Adding the new docs.

sentences = [
    "This is a system response".split(), 
    "That is a hello world thing".split()
]

documents += [TaggedDocument(doc, [i]) for i, doc in enumerate(sentences, start=len(documents))]
model = Doc2Vec(documents, vector_size=5, window=2, min_count=1, workers=4)

print('No. of docs:', len(documents))
print('No. of doc vectors:',len(model.docvecs))
print('-----')


for s, i in zip(sentences, range(len(sentences))):
    print(i+original_len)
    print(s)
    print(model.docvecs[i+original_len])
    print('-----')
```

[out]:

```
No. of original docs: 9
No. of original doc vectors: 9
-----

No. of docs: 11
No. of doc vectors: 11
-----

9
['This', 'is', 'a', 'system', 'response']
[-0.00675494 -0.09459886 -0.05916259  0.02931841  0.07335921]

-----

10
['That', 'is', 'a', 'hello', 'world', 'thing']
[ 0.06789951  0.07246465  0.00149267 -0.09202603  0.08346568]
```

Comment: Note that a total retraining, with extra documents, can be appropriate, but that doc-vectors from the separate runs won't generally be comparable. (Only vectors from the same model have meaningful distances/directions from each other.) Also, while toy settings like `vector_size=5` & `min_count=1` may be useful to make a tiny demo run, situations where this algorithm is actually helpful generally benefit from values closer to the defaults (`vector_size=100, min_count=5`), and sufficientlyu plentiful data to support such larger-vectors, & productive discard of rarer words.